# Python class that inherits, does nothing else

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm creating a package where I create about ~30 classes that all inherit from a common generic class. Generally, they add or modify methods, but every now and then, the subclass can inherit from the generic and make no modification.

What is the most pythonic way to do this? `SubClass = GenericClass` works, but it offends my aesthetic sensibilities.

Comment: Note: `SubClass = GenericClass` is *not the same* semantically as inheriting from `GenericClass`

Comment: `SubClass.__name__ == 'GenericClass'`

Comment: Is there some rich semantic reason for inheriting and not modifying the behaviour or interface?

Comment: I have class A, B, and C which all do separate tasks and inherit (and modify) from a common class GenericClass. I have a new task d to do, by happenstance no new modification is necessary. For consistency, I would like to have class D which just happens to just be the same as GenericClass but it's clear it performs task d.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could probably just..

```
class Subclass(GenericClass):
    '''this is a subclass'''
```

Comment: Just make sure to add a docstring, which'd remove the need for the `pass` and make it more PEP8-friendly (and user-friendly)